# How to close a modal by clicking on the backdrop in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have created a simple reusable modal component using Vue.js and it works fine, but I want to make so that when I click on the backdrop the modal closes, how can I achieve this? I searched and found a similar question on stackoverflow:
[vuejs hide modal when click off of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610426/vuejs-hide-modal-when-click-off-of-it)
And did the same that the accepted answer does, putting `@click="$emit('close')"` on the wrapper but the modal does not get closed by clicking the backdrop as it is in the provided example. Here is my code:

```
<template>
 <div :class="backdrop" v-show="!showModal">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container" :class="size"  @click="$emit('close')">
          <span class="close-x" @click="closeModal">X</span>
          <h1 class="label">{{label}}</h1>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot></slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'custom-modal',
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false
    };
  },
  props: {
    label: String | Number,
    size: String,
    backdrop: String
  },
  components: {
    'custom-btn': customBtn
  },
  methods: {
    closeModal() {
      this.showModal = true;
    }
  }
};

</script>

<style>
.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;

  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  transition: all .3s ease;

}

.close-x {
  color: #00A6CE;
  float: right;
}

.close-x:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 15):

**Without a library** you need to set it up like this:

```
<div class="modal-wrapper" @click="$emit('close')>
    <div class="modal-container" :class="size" @click.stop=""></div>
</div>
```

It looks like you're missing the `@click.stop=""` which is required. Additionally you want to move the `$emit('close')` up to the `modal-wrapper` level.

**With a library** it may be overkill, but this is something that I have used [v-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-click-outside) for.

> Vue directive to react on clicks outside an element without stopping the event propagation. Great for closing dialogues, menus among other things.

Simply `npm install --save v-click-outside`

Then (from the docs):
`<div v-click-outside="onClickOutside"></div>`

and:

```
  onClickOutside (event, el) {
    this.closeModal();
  },
```

Comment: How can I achieve this without using a library?

Comment: Thanks, I moved the emitting to the ```modal-wrapper``` level and added the ```@click.stop="" ``` but still nothing happens when clicking the backdrop sadly and I have no idea why.

Comment: @MahmaDeva can you create a fiddle to show the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try creating a transparent `div` that covers all the screen but with a `z-index` < your modals `z-index`. Then `@click` on it, you emit your event to close the modal :) Hope it will hellp

Comment: using this, you can also add some opacity/transparency to your closing div in order to contrast your modal

Comment: Exactly.  Most of the modals need an overlay to sit on top, so its very clever to add a click event on it like @click.prevent="closeModal".

Answer (score 3):

Use `@click.self` for parent element (for the background).

`click.self` only triggers handler if event.target is the element itself i.e. not from a child element

See https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers

```
<div class="background" @click.self="close()">
    <div>The modal window</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <template>
        <div @click="handleBackdropClick" class="backdrop" ref="backdrop">
            <div class="modal">
                <h1> Modal Title </h1>
                <input type="text" /> 
                <p> Modal Content </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <style>
    .modal {
        width: 400px;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 100px auto;
        background: white;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    .backdrop{
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .close{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
    export default {
        methods: {
            handleBackdropClick(e){
                console.log(e)
                if (e.path[0].className == "backdrop") {
                    this.$refs.backdrop.classList.add('close');
                }
                    
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: _What does this code do?_ Please read [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`@click.self`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers) event modifier on the `backdrop` ensures that the modal doesn't close when clicking inside the modal box.

Here is a live demonstration on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-aae3fg?file=src%2FApp.vue).

```
// Modal.vue
<template>
  <div class="backdrop" @click.self="closeModal">
    <div class="modal" :class="{ sale: theme === 'sale' }">
      <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
      <p>{{ text }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['heading', 'text', 'theme'],
  methods: {
    closeModal() {
      this.$emit('close');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```